# c++ vector error

Tags: c++, vector

In the .h file:

```
class counting
{
public:
    vector<int> vekto[2];
....
```

in .cpp

```
counting::counting()
{   int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    vecto[i].resize(3);//line 6
}
```

get error:

```
.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'vecto' : undeclared identifier
.cpp(6) : error C2228: left of '.resize' must have class/struct/union
```

where is problem?

P.S. in cpp the .h file is included.

Comment: Comon that's a spelling error: "vekto" not "vecto".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared your vector array as `vekto`, but you are referring to it as `vecto`. Change either of them so that they match.

Comment: @EdgarBuchvalov - If this answer answers your question, could you accept it so that appropriate credit is given?

Comment: futhermore, tel me plz if i want to call this vektor first element i have to write: vakto[i].at(1) or there is another way?

Comment: @EdgarBuchvalov You can access the element like this: `vekto[i][1];` std::vector has overloaded `operator []` so that you can use them like arrays.